# How to Fetch All Parameters in 'User Defined Java Class' Step in Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

**Scenario:**
I am creating a Transformation in PDI. This transformation Has a Step 'User Defined Java Class', In which I am calling an external library.
This Transformation have'parameters' and for now, I have to fetch all parameters ***individually*** to pass to use them in this step (passing to my external jar)like this:

```
PgSqlHost = getVariable("PostgresHost"); 
PgSqlPort = getVariable("PgSqlPort"); 
PgSqlLoginUserId = getVariable("PgSqlLoginUserId"); 
PgSqlLoginPassword = getVariable("PgSqlLoginPassword");
```

There are 50-60 params like these that I have to use in this step. and I have to fetch each of them individually and pass it to external java lib like this.

```
TransformationParameters tparams= new TransformationParameters();
tparams.PgSqlHost = PgSqlHost;
tparams.PgSqlPort = Integer.parseInt(PgSqlPort);
tparams.PgSqlLoginUserId = PgSqlLoginUserId;
tparams.PgSqlLoginPassword = PgSqlLoginPassword;
Configuration config =  ConfigurationReader.getConfiguration();
config.setParameters(tparams);
```

The problem with this approach is:

1. I have to fetch all parameters individually.
2. When Adding new parameter I have to handle modify this step in all transformations

**My question:**
Is there a way to fetch all parameters something just like this:

```
HashMap<K,V> params = getAllVariables();
Configuration config =  ConfigurationReader.getConfiguration();
config.setParametersMap(tparams);
```

**What I tried:**

1. I tried searching in Pentaho [Wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/User+Defined+Java+Class) & This [thread](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?80903-Using-Variables-in-User-Defined-Java-Class) in Forums,
   But found nothing close.
2. I could add a step to write those params to a .properties file and
   read those in my external jar.

Can someone suggest a better idea to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use such method in process row in UserDefinedJavaClass

```
String[] variables =    super.parent.listVariables();
```

Comment: Wow.. I get the map of all parameters/variables now but these are only parameter names I get. I need to fetch all parameters with their values.

Comment: And if there isn't a way to fetch a map of key values I can iterate over those keys and get their value to put those entries into the map.